# How to insert links in Python

Tags: python, html

Is it possible to add links into the Python script and print it out to the terminal/console? Like in HTML; once it was clicked, we will be redirected to the URL. (I'm on Linux)

```
<a href="URL">Click Here To Login</a>
```

Comment: For example www.facebook.com

Comment: I mean: **where** = console / webpage / gui ...

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, how are you running the python program? What do you hope to do with the finished program?

Comment: @falsetru , in Console (Linux Terminal)

Comment: Some terminals auto-link hyperlinks, but if yours does not, I don't see a way of outputting a link. Perhaps you should consider writing your program as a CGI script, or a HTTP server?

Comment: You can't output a link, you can only output a file. The program that is reading the file, will know what to do with it. Your question is quite vague; and it is not clear what it is that you actually want.

Comment: CodeNewbie, about 3.5 years after the original post, a good answer was added by @egmont. Another 3 years later, I'm here to remind you marking this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on where you want to print it out to. Some output locations do not support clickable hyperlinks.

For example, if you printed your output to a basic terminal, you would not be able to click on it.

One suggestion is to use python's `webbrowser` module to open links:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://www.example.com")
```

, which will open the link for you in a new window.

You could also output the text to a HTML file and open the HTML file in a web browser for the link:

```
open("link.html", "w").write('<a href="http://www.example.com"> Link </a>')
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently (in 2017) a few terminal emulators (namely iTerm2, GNOME Terminal, and Tilix; hopefully more to follow) have added support for custom hyperlinks.

Assuming your python app's output goes to such a terminal emulator, you can create ctrl+clickable (cmd+clickable on mac) hyperlinks like this:

```
print("\x1b]8;;http://example.com/\x1b\\Ctrl+Click here\x1b]8;;\x1b\\")
```

Further technical details are [here](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible here is a simple python cgi script that does what you describe.

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print """
<html>
<head><title>Sample</title></head>
<body>
<a href='http://google.com'>google</a>
</body></html>
"""
```

you can learn more about cgi here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Answer (score 0):

Also, just to add, some [Python](https://python.org) running applications automatically support  clickable [links](https://replit.com). All you have to do is `print("https://example.com/")`, and once you click on it, it will take you to whatever website. In this case, it is [example.com](https://example.com). One application that I know of that supports this is [Replit.com](https://repl.it).

Just so you know, if you are running it on the Python app (IDLE), then it won't work.