# How to display clickable file path in python

Tags: python

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this above content in a file("`/home/usr/hello.html`" ) in my local disc. I want to display this file path link in my console, so that user can click it to  open in browser. Can anybody suggest a way to do this in python.

Comment: Please post you code as **CODE**-Block instead of an image. It helps us to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert links in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125114/how-to-insert-links-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```