# CMS (Python/Django) user enter a Weblink on the Create Article page. How is this done?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I am new to coding and this is my first attempt at making a CMS in (Python/Django) so this may be a simple question: Along with (title, body, thumb) I want the user to be able to enter a Weblink on the Create Article page. How is this done?

Comment: The best way to get help is to try something and if it fails show where you are having problems, otherwise your question might be to broad

Comment: To be honest: If I knew enough to do that I would... Only two weeks in on this.... Artist brain trying to write code...

Comment: It is hard to know but maybe this can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125114/how-to-insert-links-in-python.  It would be like me asking how to paint a tree  to an artist,? Show your code , how are you  creating this articles it could be really simple or more complex

Comment: be.com/watch?v=l2YDT3fVv9k how about this

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by weblink you mean like example.com/path/to/page, where the 'path/to/page' part is the weblink. In this case, you need to add a field called 'slug' to your page model, and use that field to identify which page object to load in your urls.py.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I will try SlugField and see if that works. I am already using it for the page id so I have the base syntax. Thank you

Comment: So here's the issue. SlugField limits characters to basic alphanumeric, so you won't be able to have slashes in there. If you want your whole url path (including slashes and all) to be set by the slug field, you will need to use CharField, and just name the field as slug. For page id, you don't want to use slugfield: just use <pk> as the named group in urls.py, and use page.pk to put in the actual URL.